# Is Eclipse Che capable of code completion for PHP?

Tags: php, ide, code-completion, eclipse-che

Is Eclipse Che capable of code completion for PHP projects? I'm interested mostly in Symfony projects that run in Eclipse Che.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that is a work in progress going on related to this aspect : https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/2590

Answer (score 0):

Not really it just highlights.
It does close brackets and quote marks but wont complete variables or methods

Comment: This is very bad, because they do not promote strongly PHP which has a great community.

Comment: I think you can link Eclipse Che to a desktop IDE which can have code completion but that kind ruins the point of using eclipse che

Comment: I have found that is a work in progress going on related to this aspect : https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/2590

Comment: hello, how to run symfony project in eclipse?

Comment: You want to add http://${server.port.80} to the preview url field for the start apache command. run is then it should display the url by the console