# Is Eclipse Che 6.5.x (docker) capable to autocomplete php language?

Tags: php, autocomplete, ide, eclipse-che

I made the docker install of Eclipse Che but I can not get the autocomplete to work.

A similar question [was raised 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889254/is-eclipse-che-capable-of-code-completion-for-php) (more or less) but the project have change a lot since then and this install is via docker.

The IDE preferences and Language Server are correct (I think). Neither the autocomplete neither content assist are working.

**Profile/Preferences/IDE**
[image: Profile/Preferences/IDE]

**Workspace/Configure Workspace/Installers**
[image]

Is there anyone who knows how to configure Eclipse Che so that the autocomplete works in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable PHP language server, you should have a fully functional auto complete. You can give it a try with the latest tag